# Swift: Dynamically targeting UI objects - UILabels, UIImageViews

Tags: ios, swift

I'm writing an app in Swift (XCode 6.4) that contains many UILabels and UIImageViews, eg:

```
@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image3: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
//many more
```

I want to be able to write functions that can dynamically target a label or image view simply by passing a parameter:

```
func setImage (num: Int) {
let imageView = "image" + String(num)
imageView.image = "myGraphicName"
}
```

Obviously this won't work as the imageView constant is just a string such as "image3". So how do I target the UI objects based on their name? There was something in ActionScript like:

```
eval["nameofobject"].width = 125;
```

This allowed string names to be linked to object, thus accessing its methods and parameters.

Many thanks for any help.

Kw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to target a specific item by number, one approach is to design a numbering scheme, and use tags instead of names.

For example, you could number all your `UIImageView`s starting at 1000, all your `UILabel`s starting at 2000, all your `UIButton`s starting at 3000, and so on.

With these tags in place, rewrite your function as follows:

```
func setImage (tag: Int) {
    let imageView = self.view.viewWithTag(tag) as! UIImageView
    imageView.image = UIImage(named:"myGraphicName")
}
```

If you want to address a group of items in a loop, you could use `@IBOutletCollection` instead. Make an outlet collection, and add the desired `UIImageView` objects to it. When you need to perform the same action on all `UIImageView` objects, loop through all items in `@IBOutletCollection` with a for-each loop.

Comment: Thanks for you help. How do I set up a tag value to an UIImageView?

Comment: @Kwangle Click your `UIImageView` in the interface builder, choose attribute viewer, scroll down to `View`, and enter tag value into the editor for the `Tag` field.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is exactly what I'm looking for, however its not working. The line: imageView.image = "myGraphicName" is throwing an error saying that as String cannot be assigned to an UIImageView object.

Comment: @Kwangle This should be fixed now.

Comment: Thank you very much, that works perfectly. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The closest things to what are you asking are Swift and Objective-C [key-value observing](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/KVO.html) (credits to @rmaddy for mentioning this one) and Objective-C [selectors](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Selector.html). Since you say you have many similar views, why don't you put them in an array and just go through the array and do what you need for each of them. You can create such arrays directly from the storyboard. Just select the views you want in the array and go to `Connections inspector` and ctrl+drag a `Referencing outlet collection` to create a new array for your views and then just ctrl+drag the rest of the views in the same array in the same manner.

Comment: Actually, Swift and Objective-C do have this feature. It's provided by the Cocoa/Cocoa touch framework. It's known as Key-Value Coding (KVC). There's [a whole document on the subject](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i).

Comment: Well KVO is indeed a better fit than selectors but they still need an initial object, if I'm not missing something. As a note for me using KVO here seems like a million dollar solution for a 50 cents problem.

Comment: I'm not saying KVO is a good solution for this particular question. I'm just refuting the opening part of your answer.

Comment: Thanks for your useful and helpful advice.

Answer (score 0):

On top of Cocoa [KVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) and tags noted in the other answers, both pragmatic approaches for querying for Objective-C runtime visible types, you can also use [Swift reflection type Mirror](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_Mirror_Structure/index.html) that is part of the standard library to query properties of an object during runtime.

The upside to using the Swift reflection approach is that it works for Objective-C types visible in your Swift code, but also for pure Swift types (my example uses arbitrary structs `A`, `B`, `C` to demonstrate this).

```
struct A {
    let state:String
}

struct C {}

struct B {
    let x1:A
    let y1:A
    let z2:C

    var propertyValuesOfTypeC:[C] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.filter({ $0.value is C }).map({ $0.value as! C })
    }

    func propertyValues(suffix s:String, type:Any.Type) -> [Any] {
        let mirror = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return mirror.children.filter({ $0.label!.hasSuffix(s)}).map({ $0.value as! A })
    }
}

let b = B(x1:A(state:"foo"), y1:A(state:"bar"), z2:C())

print(b.propertyValues(suffix:"1", type: A.self))
print(b.propertyValuesOfTypeC)
```

This prints out:

```
[A(state: "foo"), A(state: "bar")]
[C()]
```